# Debugger actions freeze and crash apps in the simulator with "pthread_rwlock_wrlock failed cyclic metadata dependency detected"

Tags: ios, xcode

When debugging my hybrid Objective-C / Swift 3.0 app in the iOS simulator (Xcode 8.2.1, iOS 10.2 simulator), I am unable to do anything useful in the debugger. Every command I enter causes the debugger to freeze for a few seconds, then give me this message:

> objc[18146]: pthread_rwlock_wrlock failed (11)
>
> GenericCache(0x1059cfca0): cyclic metadata dependency detected, aborting
>
> expression produced error: error: Execution was interrupted, reason: signal SIGABRT.
>
> The process has been returned to the state before expression evaluation.

The app then crashes immediately after. What is causing this?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what causes it, but the problem can be "fixed" by switching the simulated device to another one. If you're particularly attached to a specific device, you can then switch back. The simulator rebooting process seems to clear it up.